# JGraph Enter/Exit/Home Listener

Tags: java, jgraphx, jgraph

I've been using the JGraph library and I can't seem to find out what event fires when the root node of the view changes. For example when you enter a group A, A is now the root of the view and when you perform the home action the view root is the defaultParent of the graph.

I found the mxEvent.ROOT event, but in the JavaScript docs (not the Javadocs) that it fires only on changes to the root on the **model**.

What event do I need to subscribe to in order to perform an action whenever the root of the **view** changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the `mxEvent.UNDO` action found in the `JS` docs [here](http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraphView-js.html#mxGraphView.Events) fires upon the `setCurrentRoot` method being called. I wish this was clearer in the Javadocs.